# Android parsing xml into character from http response

Tags: android, parsing, httpresponse

I am getting my response from http post (a php server)
However , I want to parse it to simple character. how to do that .

here is my following method which I use for HttpPost

```
public void postLoginData()
    {
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    /* login.php returns true if username and password is equal to saranga */
   // HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.sencide.com/blog/login.php");
     HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://advanmind.com/adapi/user/add/");//username and password is xyz
    try {
        // Add user name and password
        EditText usermail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        String email = usermail.getText().toString();

        EditText pword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        String password = pword.getText().toString();

        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        Log.w("ADPORTAL", "Execute HTTP Post Request");
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        String str = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
        Log.w("ADPORTAL", str);

        if(str.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("false") )
        {


            Log.w("ADPORTAL", "FALSE");
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), str, 10000).show();
            result.setText("You are not registerd please register");

            //Intent AfterLogin = new Intent(this, AfterLogin.class);
            //startActivity(AfterLogin);
        }else
        {Log.w("SENCIDE", "TRUE");

      // Intent AfterLogin = new Intent(this,AfterLogin.class);
      // startActivity(AfterLogin);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), str, 10000).show();
        //result.setText(str+" loginsuccess");   

            // Intent registration  = new Intent(this, Registration.class);
          //startActivity(registration);
        }

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

the input stream method

```
private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
    String line = "";
    StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
    // Wrap a BufferedReader around the InputStream
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    // Read response until the end
    try {
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) { 
            total.append(line); 
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // Return full string
    return total;
}
```

please tell me the detail code to parse it into character. i am using toast to view the response.thanks in advance.any problem please do comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understand your question correctly, but this code will return the response as a String (:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://advanmind.com/adapi/user/add/");
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
ResponseHandler<String> res = new BasicResponseHandler();
String response = httpclient .execute(postMethod, res);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not completely clear what you want but, within your code it looks like you want to login at `http://www.sencide.com/blog/login.php` url.

That login page returns a string "Login Failed" So you can check that string.

**Do this, unremark login url and remark add user line:**

```
  HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.sencide.com/blog/login.php")
  //HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://advanmind.com/adapi/user/add/");
```

**And change this line:**

```
if(str.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("false") )
```

**To this:**

```
if(str.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Login Failed"))
```

Comment: sorry if i posted two servers .one is [("http://advanmind.com/adapi/user/add/")] other is [("http://www.sencide.com/blog/login.php")].  But my issue is not that , I am getting a proper response from the server in xml format which i want to read as plain text not xml . suppose my xml is <data><item>abc</item><item>def</item1>. But i want to read as [Item-abc , Item-def] or something like that(without the xml nodes).Sorry if i thrown a wrong question.